# Listen for rejected promises on the front-end

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

Using node.js, we can listen for rejected promises using:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  console.log('Unhandled Rejection at:', p, 'reason:', reason);
  // application specific logging, throwing an error, or other logic here
});
```

is this the best way to listen for unhandledRejections on the front-end?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection

Comment: its looks to be by and large not supported in the front-end. There might be a library that provides a promise wrapper and tracks rejections. Not sure though.

Comment: This doesn't look like a particularly good idea to me, either frontend or backed. When you write code for a promise, it's your responsibility to make sure rejection of that promise is handled properly. There's no catch-all solution.

Comment: @DavidKnipe The catch-all is for the cases where you forgot to handle the rejections, or when the handler itself threw. Of course errors *should* be handled on the promise itself and unhandled rejections optimally *should* never happen, I assume the OP knows that.

Comment: If the handler throws then you can catch it again, if that's appropriate for the use case. You can keep trying forever until it succeeds, or give up after 3 attempts, or wait and try again later, or whatever. But given the large variety of situations in which promises are used, from the critically important to the downright silly, it's hard to see how a single handler could work for all of them.

Comment: @DavidKnipe what Bergi said. In my case, I use the catch-all for logging errors and throwing up an error notification for the user, that's all. It's not for any other logic handling. It's a last-ditch thing only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", …)` is the front-end equivalent to node's `process.on('unhandledRejection', …)`. It's not the "best" way to listen to them, it's the *only* way.